# Why I can't set image on top of div in scroll wrapper div card

Tags: html, css

I created a cards-based horizontal scroller. And the cards are nicely scrolling inside the wrapper. The issue I'm having is that even after I applied the z-index to our member-owner-card-image, the photos still go under the card when I want to put them on the top of each card.

Is there any solution so that I can add the image on top of the card? I'm trying to fix it, but no solution has been found.

```css
.scrolling-wrapper {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    height: 331px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-inline: 40px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow-x: auto;
    z-index: 0;
  }

  .scrolling-wrapper::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
  }

  .card {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

  .our-member-owner-card-image {
    position: absolute;
    top: -30px;
    z-index: 10;

  }

  .card-content {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 38px;
  }

  .member-detail {
    padding-top: 55px;
    line-height: 1.7;

  }

  .member-detail h3 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #263244;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-family: 'Lato';
  }

  .member-detail p {
    text-align: center;
    color: #737C89;
  }

  .member-description {
    padding-inline: 20px;
    color: #263244;
    line-height: 1.6;
    padding-top: 9px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 17px;
  }

  .member-description span {
    color: red;
    text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<div class="scrolling-wrapper">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="our-member-owner-card-image">
                <img width="220px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661961110144-12ac85918e40?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="member-detail">
                  <h3>Sohaib</h3>
                  <p>Chairman</p>
                </div>
                <div class="member-description">
                  Sohaib Ashraf has extensive work experience during his career
                  of more than 25 years in the financial services sector.<span
                    >Read more</span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="our-member-owner-card-image">
                <img width="220px" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661961110144-12ac85918e40?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80" />
              </div>
              <div class="card-content">
                <div class="member-detail">
                  <h3>Sohaib Ashraf</h3>
                  <p>Chairman</p>
                </div>
                <div class="member-description">
                  Sohaib Ashraf has extensive work experience during his career
                  of more than 25 years in the financial services sector.<span
                    >Read more</span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add the image as a `background-image` to the card. I added few examples how you can use `background-image`:

```css
 .card{
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: gray;
 }

.card-1, .card-2 .image, .card-3 .image{
    /* Here, we use background-image to set the image */
    background-image: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1661961110144-12ac85918e40?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDF8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=870&q=80");

    /* The background should be a cover photo, 
       so it fills the whole card: */
    background-size: cover;

    /* We don't want the image to repeat itself */
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    /* When the ratio of the image changes, it will zoom into
       this point, which we want to happen in the center of the image */
    background-position: center;

}

.card-2, .card-3{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

.card-2 .image{
    border-radius: 6px 6px 0px 0px;
}

.card-3{
    padding: 10px;
}

/* This is to demonstrate: */
h2{
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-1 card">
  <h2>Test title</h2>
</div>

<div class="card-2 card">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2> Test title</h2>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card-3 card">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2> Test title</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Adding the image in background is not the requirement.I want half in half out on top of div.

Comment: Could you describe it in a bit more in detail? Do you have a reference picture so I can help you further?

Comment: If my solution fits as an answer, you can mark it as answered.